# Update Processor returns empty String: Converting string date to long in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

Converting a string date with the format mentioned on the image to a number (long) but the output I get is empty string.

Using a JSON reader and writer;

where in input JSON it is a string and in the output JSON it is of type long.

Tried to keep the output JSON type as a String and tried to evaluate the following expression but that was also empty string

${DATE1.value:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber():toString()}

Sample data trying to convert: {"DATE1" : "2018-01-17 00:00:00"}

Tried to follow the solution on this [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/109714/nifi-processor-convert-stringdatetime-format-to-lo.html) but still getting empty string.

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in your EL expression — `toSting()` should be `toString()`.

Comment: corrected. Thanks Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1: Referring to contents of flowfile:-**

If you want to change the DATE1 value based on the field value from the content then you need to refer as **field.value**

> Replacement Value Strategy
>
> Literal Value

**//DATE1**
${field.value:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}

Referring DATE1 value from the content, then apply expression language to it. 
[image: UpdateRecord Config]

**Avro Schema Registry:-**

> {   "namespace": "nifi",   "name": "balances",   "type": "record",
>   "fields": [
>       { "name": "DATE1", "type": "string"}   ] }

Read DATE1 field value as String from the content.

**JsonRecordSetWriter:-**

> {   "namespace": "nifi",   "name": "balances",   "type": "record",
>   "fields": [
>       { "name": "DATE1", "type":"long"}    ] }

In SetWriter configure DATE1 as Long type.

**Input:-**

{"DATE1":"2018-01-17 00:00:00"}

**Output:-**

[{"DATE1":1516165200000}]

(or)

**Method 2: Referring to attribute of the flowfile:-**

if you are having DATE1 as attribute of the flowfile with value 2018-01-17 00:00:00 we are going to use DATE1 attribute instead of field.value(which refers to contents of flowfile)

Then UpdateRecord Configs would be

**Replacement Value Strategy**

> Literal Value

```
//DATE1
${DATE1:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}
```

in this Expression we are using DATE1 attribute to Update the contents of flowfile.
Both methods will result the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Check value before converts to Date by using isEmpty() and ifElse().

```
${field.value:isEmpty():ifElse('', ${field.value:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()})}
```